# How to build Visual Studio 2017 solution file for C++ in Travis CI?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, travis-ci, travis-ci-cli

I have a project in GitHub which is written in VC++17.

How to build it from Travis CI?

What should be the content of YAML file?

Comment: I guess travis does not support Visual Studio. You can use AppVeyor. Here is an [example](https://github.com/sipsorcery/bitcoin/blob/msvc/.appveyor.yml)